# Python - what are all the built-in decorators?

Tags: python, decorator

I know of `@staticmethod`, `@classmethod`, and `@property`, but only through scattered documentation. What are all the function decorators that are built into Python? Is that in the docs? Is there an up-to-date list maintained somewhere?

Comment: There isn't an official list, but this link is useful: https://github.com/lord63/awesome-python-decorator

Comment: Most famous ones are: `@staticmethod`, `@classmethod`, `@property`, `@wraps`, `@timeit`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I don't think so. Decorators don't differ from ordinary functions, you only call them in a fancier way.

For finding all of them try searching [Built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) list, because as you can see in [Python glossary](http://docs.python.org/3.0/glossary.html) the decorator syntax is just a syntactic sugar, as the following two definitions create equal functions (copied this example from glossary):

```
def f(...):
    ...
f = staticmethod(f)

@staticmethod
def f(...):
```

So any built-in function that returns another function can be used as a decorator. Question is - does it make sense to use it that way? :-)

[functools](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html) module contains some functions that can be used as decorators, but they aren't built-ins you asked for.

Answer (score 24):

They're not built-in, but [this library](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary) of example decorators is very good.

As Abgan [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480178/python-is-there-a-list-of-decorators-somewhere#480266), the built-in function list is probably the best place to look. Although, since decorators can also be implemented as classes, it's not guaranteed to be comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

Decorators aren't even required to return a function. I've used `@atexit.register` before.

Comment: Well, that one returns the same function passed to it for that very purpose.

Comment: Oh, does it? I never noticed.

Comment: "Decorators aren't even required to return a function" - in order to make any sense, though, they should, since `@decor` is just sugar for `f = decor(f)` - otherwise you will lose the reference to the function you are decorating.

Comment: @Dan, you're aware that `@property` doesn't return a function, yes?

Comment: Becouse `f=decor(f)`, the function **decor** need to return _something_. If you want to call `f` after the decoration, it need to be a function, if not, it can be anything.

Comment: @Sasszem, every function returns _something_. If nothing else, you'll at least get `None`. Either way, there are many non-function callable objects.

Answer (score -7):

There is no such thing as a list of all decorators. There's no list of all functions. There's no list of all classes.

Decorators are a handy tool for defining a common aspect across functions, methods, or classes. There are the built-in decorators. Plus there are any number of cool and useless decorators. In the same way there are any number of cool and useless classes.

Comment: His question was about builtin decorators specifically. There has to be a **finite** (and probably relatively small) list of builtin decorators.